# Maven Coordinates on Spring Cloud Data flow - Cloud Foundry

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am unable to refer a jar from my jfrog-maven repository on Spring Cloud data flow server installed on PCF. I have given the repository location inside an ENV variable SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON as  {"maven": { "remote-repositories": { "repo1": { "url": "http://XXXXX:8080/artifactory/my-releases-local/" } } } }

When I try to register an app with Spring cloud data flow UI, I try to refer the application with below sample maven coordinates.

Example:
< maven://com.example:datasource:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT >

The server is unable to find it and proceed me with registering the app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of dataflow? Also, what is the exact error? Does your PCF install has access to this repo? Many times operators will not allow external access from a private PCF install

Comment: Thank you for the response. Dataflow server I am using is 1.2 0 for cloud foundry. I tried a WGET to the repo from PCF VM and was successful.

Comment: What was your command that you used in the UI? Perhaps there's a typo in it, so let's verify that. Also, can you attach the logs of this exercise?

Comment: Could you please attach the full exception from the logs? And just to be sure, when you said you wget from the PCF VM, did you mean you ssh into a Garden container? Or you just SSH into a VM from the install. Operators can restrict access from the containers using Application Security Groups even if the VM running the Diego Cell have access to the internet. Please make sure that your container has access either via ssh into it, or if you can't by using a simple java app that tries to open a remote URL

Comment: @ViniciusCarvalho: There is no specific exception, Spring cloud dataflow does not allow me to proceed with registering the app as in the screenshot below :
http://imgur.com/a/xoZPD

Also, I have tried a wget from VM of a diego cell. Will try to push an app and see it the containers have some restriction.

Comment: Thanks, @rahul. You seem to enclose the URI within `< ... >`, which is wrong. Example: `maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:ftp-source-rabbit:1.2.0.RELEASE`

Comment: ;Ah, Thank you @SabbyAnandan for pointing it out. Was misguided by the suggestion in ui. 
Now I am able to proceed registering an app. But unable to create a stream with the below error popped on the UI: "Problem creating stream: streamname:com.my.example:dataingestor:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT. Configured remote repository"

Comment: Not sure if i was doing something wrong here. The syntax i was following is as below : 
maven://groupid:artifactid:jar:version

Comment: Is that artifact downloadable outside of SCDF? If yes, does it run via `java -jar` command? It is hard to interpret the error without knowing the artifact is actually available and visible. Also, when reporting problems, please make sure to attach the stacktrace logs - preferably as a file.